# How do I create an Android library module in Android Studio which contains debug and main packages instead?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-module

I want to create an *Android* library module which contains `main` and `debug` packages only in the *Java* root. Whenever I create a new *Android* library module, I get the usual in the *Java* root which are `main`, `androidTest` and `test`. However I want to change them to `main` and `debug` only.

Comment: Just delete them, if you are not writing tests, (you should, believe me.), it works, they are independent folders.

Comment: @Akhha8 I did what you said however I just deleted test and the androidTest,I refactored it to debug, then I deleted the file and created my own. and now everything is working perfect.I been struggling since last week Sunday. Thanks for the help. What also helped me was I switched project.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do it by means of *Android Studio*, but rather manually in a file browser.

Comment: is there any tutorial maybe on youtube that I can learn from?

Comment: No need for a tutorial. It's pretty trivial. In a file browser of your choice remove, if you'd like, the `androidTest` and `test` folders. Then create the `debug` folder that has the same sub-folders structure as of the `main` folder.

Comment: @Onik it worked I did just as you said.I removed test and refactored androidTest to debug.I then deleted the file and created my own. I first switch to project from android which brought out more details. Thanks alot mate.salute